# ImageJ, adding a scale bar to ImagePlus

Tags: java, plugins, imagej

I am trying to add a scale bar to ImagePlus but I can not. When I was using windows I used the following commands:

```
IJ.selectWindow("window_name");
IJ.run("Set Scale...", "distance=1 known="+pixelSize+" pixel=1 unit=um");
IJ.run("Scale Bar...", "width="+barSize+" height=3 font=12 color=Black location=[Upper Right]");
```

I hope someone can help me, I let the code to be seen:

```
String name = "example.jpg";
ImagePlus cRoiDuplicated = this.cROI.duplicate();
cRoiDuplicated.setTitle(name);

if (barSize != -1){
  [Code]
  /*IJ.run("Set Scale...", "distance=1 known="+pixelSize+" pixel=1 unit=um");
  IJ.run("Scale Bar...", "width="+barSize+" height=3 font=12 color=Black location=[Upper Right]");*/
}

FileSaver fs = new FileSaver(cRoiDuplicated);
fs.saveAsJpeg(this.directory + name);
cRoiDuplicated.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Java plugin, you should use the [`IJ.run(ImagePlus imp, String command, String options)`](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/ij/IJ.html#run(ij.ImagePlus,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method that takes an `ImagePlus` as first input argument.

Use the [Macro recorder](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-31.html#sub:Record...) in *Java* mode to get the required commands. The following plugin was created by

- opening the recorder window (*Plugins > Macros > Record...*),
- opening the '*Blobs*' sample image (*File > Open Samples > Blobs (25K)*),
- setting the scale (*Analyze > Set Scale...*),
- adding the scale bar (*Analyze > Tools > Scale Bar...*), and then
- clicking on the '*Create*' button in the Recorder window.

This is the generated code:

```
import ij.*;
import ij.process.*;
import ij.gui.*;
import java.awt.*;
import ij.plugin.*;
import ij.plugin.frame.*;

public class My_Plugin implements PlugIn {

    public void run(String arg) {
        ImagePlus imp = IJ.openImage("http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/images/blobs.gif");
        IJ.run(imp, "Set Scale...", "distance=1 known=2 pixel=1 unit=um");
        IJ.run(imp, "Scale Bar...", "width=50 height=3 font=12 color=Black background=None location=[Upper right]");
        imp.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, you've been very helpful. I just tested and it works.